# jQuery not working at all?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I type my code in, I label a div with a title, and put jQuery code in so that it will expand when I mouse over it. However, that doesn't seem to be working when I put it in my code?

The code I'm using is here:

http://www.codecademy.com/courseBlaster14854_53a1c3f8631fe99231000802_deleted_53a1c3f8631fe99231000802_deleted/codebits/gioGOU/edit

Comment: Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not link to the jQuery library. Try adding one of the following lines to your `<head>`:

1.x

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.x

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

E.g.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title> Risebush|home </title>
</head>
```

**UPDATE:**

Replace your script.js with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#info").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest("#info").css("z-index", 1);

        $(this).animate({
            height: "400"
        }, "fast");

    }, function () {
        $(this).closest("#info").css("z-index", 0);
        $(this).animate({
            height: "250"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: Anyone help me? It's not working at all

Comment: I have fixed your problem, please see update.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do it for the other two main divs if I give them the title #newinfo and #worldwide? Also, the text seems to shake when I mouse over it.

Comment: Yes. To fix the text jumping, set the padding instead of letting it auto adjust. Add this line to the style of the div `padding:10;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `Jquery` library in order to use it. Add the following inside your `head` tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to close document ready parenthesis

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#info').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
});
```